# Can insert into vector Out of order?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to insert `vec1` by `vec2` and `vec3`. When I insert `vec3` first, the program cannot exit successfully. But when I insert `vec2` and then insert `vec3`, the program can exit successfully.
I want to know the failed reason.

Why insert `vec1` **Out of order**: I want to insert it by two different threads( The two threads will write to different positions and do not affect each other.), so the order cannot be guaranteed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;


struct DocIdAndPayLoad
{

    uint64_t m_docId;

    DocIdAndPayLoad()
    {
        DefaultCnt++;
    }


    DocIdAndPayLoad(const DocIdAndPayLoad& /*_bond_rhs*/)
    {
        CopyCnt++;
    }


    DocIdAndPayLoad(DocIdAndPayLoad&& _bond_rhs)
    {
        MoveCnt++;
    }


    DocIdAndPayLoad& operator=(const DocIdAndPayLoad& _bond_rhs)
    {
        AssignCnt++;
        return *this;
    }


    static int DefaultCnt;
    static int CopyCnt;
    static int MoveCnt;
    static int AssignCnt;
};

int DocIdAndPayLoad::DefaultCnt = 0;
int DocIdAndPayLoad::CopyCnt = 0;
int DocIdAndPayLoad::MoveCnt = 0;
int DocIdAndPayLoad::AssignCnt = 0;

int main()
{
    const int hugeSize=10000;
    vector<DocIdAndPayLoad> vec1;
    cout<<vec1.size()<<" "<<vec1.capacity()<<endl;

    vector<DocIdAndPayLoad> vec2(hugeSize/2);
    vector<DocIdAndPayLoad> vec3(hugeSize/2);

    auto start1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    vec1.reserve(hugeSize);
    
    //vec1.insert(vec1.begin()+hugeSize/2, std::make_move_iterator(vec3.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vec3.end()));
    vec1.insert(vec1.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(vec2.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vec2.end()));
    
    auto stop1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop1 - start1);
    cout << "Cost1: "<< duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    vector<DocIdAndPayLoad> vec4;
    auto start2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    vec4.resize(hugeSize);
    auto stop2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2 - start2);
    cout << "Cost2: "<< duration2.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    cout<<vec1.size()<<" "<<vec1.capacity()<<endl;
         
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when two threads insert into the same vector you need some sort of synchronization

Comment: The two threads will write to two different positions and do not affect each other.

Comment: well, thats not what insert does. Inserting an element in a vector may cause reallocation. If you resize upfront and then access seperate elements thats fine. Btw I dont understand whats the issue with the code you posted. Thats the code that crashes?

Comment: I think `reverse` is more efficiently than `resize` because `reverse` does not call the constructor. I want to access the raw memory that `std::vector::reverse` allocate, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `reserve` call sets the *capacity* of a vector, but not its size. That means the vector will still be empty after calling

```
vec1.reserve(hugeSize);
```

Any indexing in that vector will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior.

More importantly, since the vector is empty, `vec1.begin()` will return the *end* iterator (i.e. `vec1.begin() == vec1.end()`), so `vec1.begin()+hugeSize/2` is *invalid!*.

Attempting to dereference the `end` iterator (or beyond) leads to undefined behavior and possible crashes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have the solution of question that I mentioned(insert it by two different threads)? I cannot use resize, because the constructor cost of DocIdAndPayLoad is too costly.

Comment: @Alfred Why not let each thread work on their own vector, and when all threads are finished insert into the final vector (`vec1`) in the required order?

Comment: *insert in the required order* make it sequential, which should be parallel because the insert is too costly.

Comment: How can I write the raw memory that `reserve` allocate?

Comment: @Alfred Perhaps you need to use "raw memory" in the form of an actual array, and then use a view of that array if you want a container-like object? Or use a different container? Have you experimented with e.g. deques or lists or other custom containers?

Comment: @Alfred Or, if the `DocIdAndPayLoad` class really is so expensive to create, perhaps it can be redesigned to be ore light-weight, especially in construction? Is it really correctly designed and implemented? OR maybe use a container of *pointers* to `DocIdAndPayLoad`?